# Custom binding not getting called in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am following some tutorials and trying to learn `knockout.js`.
I am not able to call the Custom Bindings.

My Custom Binding JS code:

```
/// <reference path="knockout-3.3.0.debug.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js" />

ko.bindingHandlers.executeOnEnter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (data, event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13) {
                allBindings.executeOnEnter.call(viewModel);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

And I am binding it using the following code:

```
 <input type="text" data-bind="executeOnEnter: addData" />
```

However, nothing happens. Even if an `alert` is set on the custom binding function nothing happens really which definitely means, it is not getting called.

Comment: Is that all your code? Are you calling: ko.applyBindings? Where is your view model, with the 'addData' method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working version,

```
ko.bindingHandlers.executeOnEnter = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        $(element).keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                allBindings.executeOnEnter.call(viewModel);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

I removed the following line to make this work for you.

```
var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
```

and then replaced `keyCode` with `event.keyCode`

Thanks

```
self.CallAlert = function () {
    alert('Alert called!');
};

<input type="text" data-bind="executeOnEnter: CallAlert" class="form-control"/>
```